# Error al compilar React-native-firebase en Android [EXPO]

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

Estoy intentando hacer un Servidor Push de notificaciones y su respectivo cliente.

Hice un servidor con Node y express y esto esperando a probarlo. Para ello estoy desarrollando un cliente en React Native + Expo + react-native-firebase.

Mi objetivo es hacer el cliente para poder desarrollar pruebas pero estoy teniendo muchos problemas. Al compilarlo tanto con `expo run:android` o con `npx react-native-android` me acaba apareciendo el siguiente error:

- Con `npx react-native-android`

```
 ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.

See http://invertase.link/android for full setup instructions.

This error is located at:
    in App (at withDevTools.js:18)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:127)
    in RCTView (at View.js:116)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:155)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:50)
    in main(RootComponent) (at renderApplication.js:67), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().
```

- Con `expo run:android`

```
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. FAILURE: Build failed with 
an exception. * What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' (type 'MergeResources'). - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'C:\Users\aamaro\Desktop\Cliente Node 6\sicongresos\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\android\build\generated\res\resValues\debug'. Reason: Task ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' uses this output of task ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Possible solutions: 1. Declare task ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' as an input of ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources'. 2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn. 3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-firebase_app:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-firebase_app:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter. For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD 
FAILED in 58s.
```

Llevo 3 días atascado en este punto y no consigo salir. He visto muchos hilos al respecto. Unos me hablan de que no es compatible la librería react-native-firebase con Expo. Otras hablan de el compilador SDK. Otros de seguir los pasos sugeridos y editar el MainApplication. O quizás utilizar `npx jetify`. En este punto he probado muchas cosas y me encuentro perdido por lo que cualquier ayuda se agradecerá mucho.

- Referencias seguidas

https://openwebinars.net/blog/configurar-react-native-desde-cero-con-expo/

https://scientyficworld.org/push-notification-firebase-cloud-messaging/